# How can I convert the following code to a Compiled Expression in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I have a piece of code which is responsible for creating a generic list using reflection.

```
public static IList MakeList(Type listType)
{
    // checks to ensure listType is a generic list omitted...

    // gets the generic argument e.g. string for a List<string>
    var genericType = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    return (IList)typeof(List<>)
        .MakeGenericType(genericType)
        .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
        .Invoke(null);
}
```

Which I can invoke by:

```
var stringList = MakeList(typeof(IList<string>));
var intList = MakeList(typeof(IList<int>));
```

or for instance from a `PropertyInfo`:

```
MekList(propInfo.PropertyType);
```

Please note that since the type could come from the `PrpertyInfo` e.g. if the type of the property is `IList<string>` then using `Activator.CreateInstance(propType)` throws an exception of: `Cannot create an instance of an interface.`

How can I convert this to a compiled expression to benefit from the performance benefits?

Comment: do you know the `listType` at compile time?

Comment: No, `listType` is not known at the compile type, updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Do you need to instantiate like a million of those per second for the 'benefit' to be a real benefit?

Comment: `return new List<string>();`

Comment: Yes Ondrej this piece of code will be used in a hot path and the question is asked purely to address optimization.

Comment: So then for sure you've measured this had a performance impact, right?

Comment: @MaYaN Have you tried return (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType)? Also, why are you doing all these checks and getting the argument and re-creating `typeof(List<>)...` ? Why do you need to exclude non-`List<>` types that implement IList?

Comment: @Random832 `Activator` throws an exception (updated the question) excluding non List is intentional due to other requirements.

Comment: OK I am on my phone now but I'll update my code in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [NewExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346083(v=vs.110).aspx). Example (I haven't tested):

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Func<IList>> funcs;
public static IList MakeList(Type listType)
{
    Func<IList> f;
    // checks to ensure listType is a generic list omitted...
    if(!funcs.TryGetValue(listType, out f)) {
        // gets the generic argument e.g. string for a List<string>
        var genericType = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var ctor = typeof(List<>)
                   .MakeGenericType(genericType)
                   .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        f = Expression.Lambda<Func<IList>>(
            Expression.New(ctor, new Expression[]{})).Compile();
        funcs[listType] = f;
    }
    return f();
}
```

Make sure you measure the performance to check that this really is faster than simply using Activator.CreateInstance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Random832` I ended up with:

```
public static class New
{
    public static readonly Func<Type, IList> MakeList = t => MakeListImpl(t)();

    private static readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<IList>> Cache = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IList>>();
    private static Func<IList> MakeListImpl(Type listType)
    {
        Func<IList> result;
        if (!Cache.TryGetValue(listType, out result))
        {
            Ensure.That(listType.IsGenericList());
            var genericArg = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var concreteType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(genericArg);

            result = Expression.Lambda<Func<IList>>(Expression.New(concreteType)).Compile();
            Cache[listType] = result;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Benchmarks** (Release build | avg 1000 runs)

```
1,000,000
------------------------------------
Native:             00:00:00.0103980
ActivatorGeneric:   00:00:00.1274370
ActivatorType:      00:00:00.1115370
CompiledNew:        00:00:00.0261892

10,000,000
------------------------------------
Native:             00:00:00.1040899
ActivatorGeneric:   00:00:01.2864721
ActivatorType:      00:00:01.1627026
CompiledNew:        00:00:00.2432613
```

---

```
NewListNative           => list = new List<string>()
NewListActivatorGeneric => list = System.Activator.CreateInstance<List<string>>()
NewListActivatorType    => list = (List<string>) System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<string>))
CompiledNew             => list = (List<string>)New.MakeList(typeof(List<string>))
```

Comment: I'd put the Ensure inside the if(!trygetvalue) so that you're not running that check more than once for the ones that are valid. And I'm not entirely sure that your use of two levels of function calls and an extra delegate doesn't have a performance cost.

Answer (score 0):

If you always use `typeof(...)`, you can also use a generic method like this:

```
public static IList<T> MakeList<T>()
{
    return new List<T>();
}
```

You use it this way:

```
var stringList = MakeList<string>();
var intList = MakeList<int>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately using `typeof(...)` is not the only way this method would be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the type at compile time, you can not write it the way you want. You can call the same methods it your code snippet with Expression, but it will be the same. Try with `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(WhatEver))`.

---

I tested your code and Activator class CreateInstace method 10 thousand instances 100 times and the results are:

1. For MakeList: 13 miliseconds
2. For CreateInstance 0.8 miliseconds

Comment: I cannot use `Activator`, I have updated the question to clarify.